# SVG element coming partially below another SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, zooming, geojson

I am drawing a map using d3.js and geojson file.
Map is getting generated properly and also map is drawn using many path for each district of that country.
Using the long,lat of a city I am drawing a circle at the projected point because I want to apply transformation like zooming and paning of the map.

The problem is that circle is partially coming below the path.

Below is the layout of HTML page.
The reason I have put circles in g tag is because I am applying zoom and pan to map and the circle should also move accordingly.

```
svg
   g
    path d=.....
    circle...some attributes
   g
    path
    circle
   g
    path
   g
    path
   g
    path
    circle
```

How can I solve the problem or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout, the paths of each region are drawn before the circles, but the circles from previous regions could be hidden by paths drawn later. You may want to create a group for the paths, append a group for the circles and a last one for the labels in order to avoid the overlapping.

```
- g.zoom
    - g.paths
        - path
        - path
        - ...
    - g.circles
        - circle
        - ...
    - g.labels
        - text...
```

You can bind the zoom behavior to the `g.zoom` group. Regards,

Comment: This is what I am doing.First I am creating map,once it is rendered then I draw circles.But the issue is still coming.

Comment: The structure of the SVG says otherwise. The elements will be shown as they are in the SVG structure, not following the rendering order. For instance, the path of the second group will be drawn over the circle of the first group, regardless of which was rendered first.

Comment: @Pablo..One more thing.I want the behavior of mouse hover on circles in which on mouse hover the radius of circle is increased.The thing is that for the circles which are close to each other when I hover over them ,the one which is drawn earlier is transited to new radius but then it comes below the other circle..I want that on mouse hover any particular circle should always be over other circle irrespective of the positioning in HTML page.

Comment: Add another group with invisible circles. When the user moves the mouse over a circle, make the circle visible (with the same color that the first one) and increase its radius. All the circles of this group will be over the other ones, and the hover circle will be the only one showing up (the others are invisible).

Comment: okay I understand your logic.but how do I draw invisible circle.

Comment: With fill-opacity: 0.0. Consider creating a new question for this.